# How to access field analyzer inside SearchComponent's subclass?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have such component:

```
public class TempComponent extends SearchComponent {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchComponent.class);


    @Override
    public void prepare(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {

        LOG.info("Temp Component ---");
        SolrIndexSearcher indexSearcher = rb.req.getSearcher();
        IndexReader reader = indexSearcher.getIndexReader();

        SolrParams params = rb.req.getParams();
        String q = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
        Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("name", q));
        DocList matchDocs = indexSearcher.getDocList(query, null, null, 0, 100000,10000);

    }
    @Override
    public void process(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in schema I designed new fieldType for field **name**.

```
<fieldType name="nameType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

<field name="name" type="nameType" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

How to access this fieldType's analyzer and apply it to query(q) before doing search to index?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TempComponent extends SearchComponent {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchComponent.class);


    @Override
    public void prepare(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {

        LOG.info("Temp Component ---");
        SolrIndexSearcher indexSearcher = rb.req.getSearcher();
        IndexReader reader = indexSearcher.getIndexReader();

        SolrParams params = rb.req.getParams();
        String q = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
        Analyzer analyzer = rb.req.getSchema().getField("name").getType().getQueryAnalyzer();
        StandardQueryParser standardQueryParser = new StandardQueryParser();
        standardQueryParser.setAnalyzer(analyzer);
        Query query = standardQueryParser.parse(q, "name");
        DocList matchedCategories = indexSearcher.getDocList(query, null, null, 0, 100000,10000);


    }
    @Override
    public void process(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I found answer! It is easy.